# NP $\subsetneq$ EXP?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, np

I think I heard in somewhere that it has been proven that $\mathsf{NP}$ is strictly contained in $\mathsf{EXP}$, that is $\mathsf{NP} \subsetneq \mathsf{EXP}$. Is this right? Wikipedia and book resources do not seem to bring me an answer..

I just found a post similar to this, but I am not sure whether $\mathsf{NP}$ is *strictly* contained in $\mathsf{EXP}$.

Comment: I remember that the answer is yes, but I don't remember the proof

Comment: [The article on "computability" from the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/computability/) says that "it is not even known that … NP is different from EXPTIME" and also "The only known proper inclusion from [ $P\subseteq NP\subseteq PSPACE \subseteq EXPTIME$ ] is that P is strictly contained in EXPTIME."
But the article was last revised in 2008, so may not be current.

Comment: And the section on EXPTIME at [the Complexity Zoo](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo:E#exp) does not mention that it is strictly larger than PSPACE, only that "There exist oracles relative to which… EXP does not equal PSPACE".

Comment: Wikipedia has a nice page on this, namely on the [time hierarchy theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem).

Comment: Note that this question can not be answered  authoritatively if the answer is "no"; who can claim to have read all papers on the topic?

Comment: @Raphael, are you sure about the intention of the OP that you have edited the question in this way?

Comment: @Kaveh: The way I see it, I only fixed notation. If the OP intended the meaning you seem to have read into the question (unlikely, imho), they may re-edit themselves.

Comment: @Raphael, the last line of the question makes that interpretation less likely, imho.

Comment: I think even $\mathsf{ZPP} = \mathsf{EXP}$ is open.

Comment: As far as I know, it is only proven by the [time hierarchy theorem][1] that $NP \subset NEXP$ and $P \subset EXP$. Maybe you have confused the results.


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem

Comment: See this <https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/56323/why-is-np-in-exptime>

Comment: See this <https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/56323/why-is-np-in-exptime>

Answer (score 5):

*Strictly contained* means $\subsetneq$, i.e. it is the definition, it is not a result. So what you are saying is 
$$\mathsf{NP} \subsetneq \mathsf{ExpTime} \implies \mathsf{NP} \subsetneq \mathsf{ExpTime}$$
 which is trivially true.

If you are asking if $\mathsf{NP}\subsetneq \mathsf{ExpTime} $ then the answer is: *it is unknown*.

You may want to check the Wikipedia article about [Exponential Time *Hypothesis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis) which many experts *believe* is true.

Comment: I think that the symbol “->” in the question is just a sloppy notation for “or equivalently,” not the symbol for logical implication, but I am not sure.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, might be (though I have seen it used that way before), but it looks unlikely to me since the OP *heard* this.

Comment: Why did you mention the exponential time hypothesis?  It is a stronger variant of the hypothesis P≠NP, and whether the ETH holds or not is not related to whether NP=EXP or NP≠EXP (as far as I know).

Comment: I would like to remark that it is known that $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{EXP}$ and $\mathsf{NP} \neq \mathsf{NEXP}$ by time hierarchy theorem.

Comment: I also don't understand the relevance of exponential time hypothesis. There is only the trivial $\mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{EXP} \Rightarrow \text{exponential time hypothesis}$, but I don't see any relationships in the other direction...

Comment: @Artem: How do you prove the implication NP=EXP ⇒ ETH?  I do not know how to prove it, and definitely it does not sound trivial to me because both NP and EXP are insensitive to the difference among polynomially equivalent problems whereas the ETH is about specific NP-complete problems (namely k-SAT).

Comment: I didn't have a formal relation in mind, yet I thought that the OP might be interested in it, it is what people usually mean that you need exponential time to solve NP-complete problems, not that $\mathsf{NP}=\mathsf{ExpTime}$.

Comment: The hypothesis “you need exponential time to solve NP-complete problems” has almost nothing to do with the current question, and the ETH is even farther from the current question.  I think that your answer is confusing because it mentions the ETH as if it had anything to do with the question.

Comment: But if you feel nothing wrong with this answer, then there is nothing I can do about it.